# Array issue ; Swift : Cannot convert type String to 'Question?'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

As a prelude, I am new to swift.

I am building an app from a class, that has a model with an array in it. Accessing the array I am attempting to set the label text with a new question.

The error I receive from xCode is 
`Cannot convert value of type 'Question?' to specified type 'String'`

In my Model, I have a .swift file with the following defining my question class

```
  class Question {

    let questionText : String
    let answer : Bool

    init(text: String, correctAnswer: Bool) {
        questionText = text
        answer = correctAnswer
    }
}
```

in another .swift I have the actual array of questions.

```
class QuestionBank {
    var list = [Question]()

    init() {

        let item = Question(text: "Valentine\'s day is banned in Saudi Arabia.", correctAnswer: true)


        list.append(item)


        list.append(Question(text: "A slug\'s blood is green.", correctAnswer: true))

        list.append(Question(text: "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", correctAnswer: true))



    }
}
```

My Main Storyboard contains the following code. This is where I receive my actual error; It seems like the [Question] pulling from my class definition of question is being interpreted by Swift as a data type, which should have been a string.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

       let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
       var pickedAnswer : Bool = false


    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
        questionLabel.text = firstQuestion!.questionText

    }


    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            print("True")
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            print("False")
        }


    }


    func updateUI() {

    }


    func nextQuestion() {
        var newQuetion : String = allQuestions.list.randomElement()



    }


    func checkAnswer() {

    }


    func startOver() {

    }



}
```

What am I doing wrong with my data type, last I checked, question? isn't a type of data set and  "Cannot convert value of type 'Question?' to specified type 'String' leads me to believe I have a data type issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don’t annotate types (`newQuetion : String`) the compiler can infer. You made it worse and caused the error. By the way I buy an `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is perfectly straightforward. You are saying:

```
var newQuetion : String = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
```

But `allQuestions.list` is an array of Question, not an array of String. Thus a random element of that array is a Question, not a String. You are insisting that `newQuetion` (sic) be a String. It isn't. Just write

```
var newQuetion = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
```

and proceed from there. Your `newQuetion` will now be an Optional Question. If you need a string, you must unwrap the Optional Question and get its `questionText`.

Answer (score -2):

This won't compile, since the object returned from randomElement isn't an instance of String but Question

```
var newQuetion : String = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
```

Should be:

```
var newQuetion : Question? = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
```

It's important that `Question?` is an optional because `Array<Element>.randomElement()` returns `Element?`

Comment: Actually, no, it's not a Question either, so that also won't compile. You're making the same mistake the OP is making: you think you know better than the compiler what type this thing will be.

Comment: @matt you are correct, of course. allQuestions.list.randomElement() returns an optional Question

Comment: It's not that it SHOULD be `Question?`, it's that it **MUST** be `Question?` because that's what the function returns.

Comment: @iAdjunct Yes, that's what I meant. My only excuse is that English isn't my first language...